# Prettier is giving inconsistent results on different machines

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prettier

My colleague and I are working on same project in different parts of app.
But we got certain files which his prettier and my prettier are overwriting each time we push our code to the github.
Here is the example of his prettier:

```
const initialState = {
  login: {
    testValue1: "hello",
    testValue2: "world",
    testValue3: true,
    testValue4: "SomeValue",
  },
} as unknown as { example: InitialState; example1: ExampleState };
```

Example of my prettier:

```
const initialState = ({
 login: {
    testValue1: "hello",
    testValue2: "world",
    testValue3: true,
    testValue4: "SomeValue",
  },
} as unknown) as { example: InitialState; example1: ExampleState };
```

So the difference are brackets which one machine putting there and another one is removing.
How can we solve this small issue and have a consistent Prettier?

Forgot to mention that I have `.prettierrc`:

```
{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false
}
```

Comment: To maintain a consistent prettier you can add `"prettier"` key to package.json or add `.prettierrc` to your directory with custom config. You can read more about config [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)  and options to configure [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)

Comment: Sorry but I have prettierrc. Updated the question

Comment: Are the versions of prettier and typescript the same on both machines?

Comment: If you mean package.json then yes

Comment: You can `npx tsc --version` and `npx prettier --version` to double check. Also what editor(s) are you using - are you using a prettier plugin that might have a different version? If you both format the file with prettier at the command line do you get the same result as your editor? Something else unlikely - is one of your editors configured with unix vs windows line endings?

Comment: @AndyRay after running npx prettier --version I found out that we have different versions of prettier.
He has 2.1.2 which is identical to the one we have in project
I have 2.5.1 which is different.
What is happening is that each time his and my editor(VSCODE) complaining about prettier and running prettier:write adding brackets on his macbook and removing on my macbook.
Do you think that I should change the version of prettier?

Comment: You should both be using the latest version of prettier, `npm update prettier`

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem

What i did:

1. `npx prettier --version` to check what version installed in `node_modules/`. (in my case versions from package.json and one from `node_modules/` were different)
2. `rm -rf node_modules` to delete node_modules folder
3. `yarn` or `npm install`

Done.

Comment: Same issue here. We were on a different version of Prettier.